# Does Javascript have higher precedence than CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code,

```js
const redSquare = document.querySelector('.red-square');
redSquare.style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
```

```css
.red-square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-square"></div>
```

red-square is colored in crimson in CSS, but in Javascript it is colored limegreen. So kind of like how IDs have higher priority than Classes, can it be said that Javascript have higher priority than CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *JavaScript* that has higher precedence, it's rules directly on the element (in the `style` attribute). Yes, those have higher precedence than CSS rules from a stylesheet — unless the CSS rules have `!important` on them (but using `!important` is a last-ditch thing). (The `style` rules can override that by using `!important`.)

The rules are [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity):

> **6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specificity**
>
> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= `a`) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so `a=1`, `b=0`, `c=0`, and `d=0`.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= `b`)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= `c`)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= `d`)
>
> The specificity is based only on the form of the selector. In particular, a selector of the form `"[id=p33]"` is counted as an attribute selector (`a=0`, `b=0`, `c=1`, `d=0`), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the source document's DTD.
>
> Concatenating the four numbers `a-b-c-d` (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.
>
> Some examples:
>
> ```css
> *             {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,0,0 */
> li            {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,0,1 */
> li:first-line {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> specificity = 0,0,0,2 */
> ul li         {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> specificity = 0,0,0,2 */
> ul ol+li      {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=3 -> specificity = 0,0,0,3 */
> h1 + *[rel=up]{}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,1,1 */
> ul ol li.red  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=3 -> specificity = 0,0,1,3 */
> li.red.level  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=2 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,2,1 */
> #x34y         {}  /* a=0 b=1 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,1,0,0 */
> ```
>
> ```
> style=""          /* a=1 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 1,0,0,0 */
> ```
>
> ```html
> <HEAD>
> <STYLE type="text/css">
>   #x97z { color: red }
> </STYLE>
> </HEAD>
> <BODY>
> <P ID=x97z style="color: green">
> </BODY>
> ```
>
> In the above example, the color of the `P` element would be green. The declaration in the "style" attribute will override the one in the `STYLE` element because of cascading rule 3, since it has a higher specificity.

and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#preshint)

> **6.4.4 Precedence of non-CSS presentational hints**
>
> The UA may choose to honor presentational attributes in an HTML source document. If so, these attributes are translated to the corresponding CSS rules with specificity equal to 0, and are treated as if they were inserted at the start of the author style sheet. They may therefore be overridden by subsequent style sheet rules. In a transition phase, this policy will make it easier for stylistic attributes to coexist with style sheets.
>
> For HTML, any attribute that is not in the following list should be considered presentational: abbr, accept-charset, accept, accesskey, action, alt, archive, axis, charset, checked, cite, class, classid, code, codebase, codetype, colspan, coords, data, datetime, declare, defer, dir, disabled, enctype, for, headers, href, hreflang, http-equiv, id, ismap, label, lang, language, longdesc, maxlength, media, method, multiple, name, nohref, object, onblur, onchange, onclick, ondblclick, onfocus, onkeydown, onkeypress, onkeyup, onload, onload, onmousedown, onmousemove, onmouseout, onmouseover, onmouseup, onreset, onselect, onsubmit, onunload, onunload, profile, prompt, readonly, rel, rev, rowspan, scheme, scope, selected, shape, span, src, standby, start, style, summary, title, type (except on LI, OL and UL elements), usemap, value, valuetype, version.
>
> For other languages, all document language-based styling must be translated to the corresponding CSS and either enter the cascade at the user agent level or, as with HTML presentational hints, be treated as author level rules with a specificity of zero placed at the start of the author style sheet.
>
> The following user style sheet would override the font weight of 'b' elements in all documents, and the color of 'font' elements with color attributes in XML documents. It would not affect the color of any 'font' elements with color attributes in HTML documents:
>
> ```css
> b { font-weight: normal; }
> font[color] { color: orange; }
> ```
>
> The following, however, would override the color of font elements in all documents:
>
> ```css
> font[color] { color: orange ! important; }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that HTML loads from top to bottom. The head loads first, then the body, and then everything inside the body. Here style tag applies crimson as background-color, then script tag overrides this with limegreen.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** a *CSS vs Javascript* issue.

Check the following example:

HTML:

```
<div class="item bg-red">item 1</div>
<div class="item" style="background: red"> item 2</div>
<div class="item bg-red-important">item 3</div>
<div id="myItem" style="background: red">item 4</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.bg-red-important {
  background: red !important;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach((item) => {
    item.style.background = 'green';
})

document.querySelector('#myItem').classList.add('bg-green');
```

**Item 1** & **Item 2** will become green because javascript is applied directly to these elements, thus, it overrides CSS style.

However, **Item 3** will remain red because of the `!important` rule.
**Item 4** will also remain red because even though we add `.bg-green` class, a style attribute is applied directly to the element.

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ae9okfj/1/